# How to read the Prerequisites of an MSI file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

We are facing a problem with the Visual Studio Addin for creating Setup files in VS2013. Becuase of this problem we are not able to Change the Prerequisites for the Target framework when we has compiled the setup once. Even when we completely disable the Prerequisites, the Prerequisites that are used at the first compile, are validated on start.

To Verify this problem as a problem of the Addin, i would like to check the Prerequisites of the created MSI file. How is that possible?

Regards

Comment: I suspect you have a launch condition in setup project for the NET framework that you haven't deleted. That is the only one to my knowledge. This may be because you added managed code custom actions so the MSI will fail without the NET runtime installed.

Comment: We checked that of cause, for example be closing the solution and open it again. The changes are made in the project file but not inside the created setup